Is there an Unreal C++ function to parse a byte array to an FString with specific encoding?
I am working on an Unreal Engine 5 project where I need to parse binary files. These files contain text encoded in Shift-JIS, as opposed to UTF-8 encoding. My goal is to convert a byte array from this binary file into an FString, but specifically interpreted using Shift-JIS encoding.
I've been searching around the web for a potential solution, but haven't seemed to find anything that addresses this specific issue. Ideally, I am looking for a function or method in Unreal C++ that can decode the byte array using Shift-JIS encoding, and convert it to an FString.
Does Unreal have built-in support for this kind of conversion? Or if not, are there any third-party libraries or custom solutions I could use otherwise to achieve this functionality?
If it helps anything, I am very flexible on how the function could work, so long as I have a correct FString representation of the string in the end, too. I have no specific requirements other than achieving the conversion.

Might ICU help you?

You can try something like this
FString ByteArrayToString(const TArray<uint8>& ByteArray, EStringEncoding Encoding)
{
    FString Result;

    if (ByteArray.Num() > 0)
    {
        switch (Encoding)
        {
            case EStringEncoding::UTF8:
                Result = FString(UTF8_TO_TCHAR(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ByteArray.GetData()), ByteArray.Num()));
                break;
            case EStringEncoding::ASCII:
                Result = FString(ANSI_TO_TCHAR(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ByteArray.GetData()), ByteArray.Num()));
                break;
            default:
                checkf(false, TEXT("Unsupported encoding"));
                break;
        }
    }

    return Result;
}

This function takes a TArray (a byte array) and an EStringEncoding enum value as input, and returns an FString object.
The function uses the StringConv.h header file, which provides functions for converting between different string encodings.
You can use this function like this:
TArray<uint8> ByteArray =...; // your byte array
FString String = ByteArrayToString(ByteArray, EStringEncoding::UTF8);

Note that this function assumes that the byte array contains a null-terminated string. If your byte array does not contain a null-terminated string, you may need to modify the function accordingly.

This doesn't work for me, as stated in my question the encoding used for the strings is Shift-JIS, which cannot be decoded by UTF-8 or ASCII
